# Unity C# Stopwatch pause from first scene and resume in second scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 3D project where when the game starts a stopwatch should starts and when the scene is changing the stopwatch should continues and does not reset.

I have implemented the stopwatch this way:

```
public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Stopwatch timer;
    public GUIStyle textStyle;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        timer = new Stopwatch ();
        timer.Start();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }


    void OnGUI()
    {

        textStyle.fontSize = 30;
        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "Timer: " + timer.Elapsed.ToString(), textStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess your stopwatch does not work as you want, what is you issue precisely ?

Comment: One thing you should know, you should not be using OnGUI for in game UI anymore, it should only be used when designing controls for the editor. Please read the first paragraph of the [Unity Scripting guide on Immediate Mode GUI](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no question I will try to use my *"magic skills"* and figure out what you need.

First guess is that you need to mark `Timer` object with `DontDestroyOnLoad()` call to not destroy this object when new scene loads. :

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: After doing this you will likely want to make the Stopwatch a non static object too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I agree, but this is just my guess so I didnt want to get into more details till I'll get some feedback from OP.